# Find only exact match using td:contains

Tags: jquery, selector, contains

I know this has been asked several times but it doesn't work for me. I have this:

```
$("td:contains('Hello')").html("Hi");                   
$("td:contains('Hello World')").html("Bye");
```

I've done this:

```
$("td:contains('Hello')").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() == "Hi";
});
```

But both are coming up "Hi". I only want table data with the exact string "Hello" to be replaced with "Hi". The "Hello World" should be replaced with "Bye", but this is not so. Can someone please help?

Comment: run the more specific command first (i.e. the Hello World) then run the less specific contains.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to want this :

```
$("td").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() == "Hello";
}).text('Hi');
```

Comment: this one works. I knew it was this simple. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`contains` is a sub-string match. the first operation you do will replace **ANY** node that has `Hello` in it ANYWHERE, so `Hello World` will be destroyed. The second line will then not match anything, because there are no more `Hello World` nodes in the document.

If you'd simply reverse the order of operations:

```
$("td:contains('Hello World')").html("Bye");
$("td:contains('Hello')").html("Hi");
```

then it'd work as expected